# Adding a function to multiple groups in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am trying to add a function to multiple groups but it does not seems to be working.

I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#modules)

Here are the comments I added:

```
/**
 * \defgroup version1 version 1
 */

/**
 * \defgroup version2 version 2
 */

/**
 * \ingroup version1 version2
 */
BOOL CLoginFormDlg::OnInitDialog(){}
```

The function only appears in the version2 module and not in the version1 module.

if I write version1 last like this:

```
/**
 * \ingroup version2 version1
 */
BOOL CLoginFormDlg::OnInitDialog(){}
```

then the function only appears in the version1 module and not the version2 module.

I would like them to appear in both modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#modules) you provided includes a paragraph that explains why it doesn't work:

> Note that compound entities (like classes, files and namespaces) can be put into multiple groups, but members (like variable, functions, typedefs and enums) can only be a member of one group (this restriction is in place to avoid ambiguous linking targets in case a member is not documented in the context of its class, namespace or file, but only visible as part of a group).

One approach to consider to solve this problem might be to create different Doxygen projects for each version of your code. You would create a Doxyfile for each version.

In this case, instead of trying to *include* common code in both sets of documentation using the `\ingroup` command, you would be *excluding* unrelated code from each set using conditional sections delimited by either `\if`...`\endif` or `\cond`...`\endcond`.

So in your version1 module, you would do the following:

```
/**
 * \if _VERSION1_
 */

    <all code in your version1 module>

/**
 * \endif
 */
```

and in your version2 module:

```
/**
 * \if _VERSION2_
 */

    <all code in your version2 module>

/**
 * \endif
 */
```

Code that needs to appear in both modules, such as your `BOOL CLoginFormDlg::OnInitDialog(){}` function, would have no such conditional commands, so would be included in both sets of documentation.

In your version1 Doxyfile, add the following line:

```
ENABLED_SECTIONS = _VERSION1_
```

and in your version2 Doxyfile:

```
ENABLED_SECTIONS = _VERSION2_
```

To link your version1 and version2 documentation sets together, you can use Doxygen's [tag file](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html) mechanism.

**See also**

- [\cond](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond)
- [\if](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdif)
- [ENABLED_SECTIONS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_enabled_sections)
- [Tag files](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html)